# Learning Python and got stuck in matrix multplication

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, nested, matrix-multiplication

```
def matrixmulti(mat1,mat2):

result=[]
'''
for i in range(len(mat1)): 


    for j in range(len(mat2[0])): 


        for k in range(len(mat2)): 
            result[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j]
            print (result[i][j])
'''
result = [[sum(a * b for a, b in zip(mat1_row, mat2_col))  
                    for mat2_col in zip(*mat2)] 
                            for mat1_row in mat1] 

for i in range(len(mat1)):
    for j in range(len(mat2[0])):
        print(mat[i][j],end=" ")
    print()
```

I was trying first with nested for loops and for some reason it didn't execute, but same thing happening to the nested list.
Can anyone help me where and what I am doing wrong?
I just passed the functions with two matrices which are initialised globally.

Comment: Could you show the whole code (with correct identation)? I ran some tests and both versions work fine.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html

Comment: matmul function implements the semantics of the @ operator, won't get any easier :)

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistake you have made in the code that you can fix to make it work.
I've made a fixed triple-loop version with some comments here to show how it can be done correctly:

```
def matrixmulti(mat1,mat2):
    # <-- code in functions needs to be indented in python for it to be considered inside the function!

    if len(mat1[0]) != len(mat2): # Optional: check if "inner" dimensions match and throw an exception if they don't
        raise ValueError("matrices dimensions does not match")

    # initializing the result matrix to all zeroes. "_" means we don't care about the value of a variable
    result = [ [ 0 for _ in range(len(mat1)) ] for _ in range(len(mat2[0])) ]

    # doing the naive triple for-loop calculation
    for i in range(len(mat1)): 
        for j in range(len(mat2[0])):
            for k in range(len(mat2)): 
                result[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j]

    # don't forget to return the results! otherwise you function is not super helpful
    return result

# heres the matrix printing wrapped up in a function
def print_matrix(matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
            print(matrix[i][j],end=" ")
        print()

multiplied = matrixmulti(mat1, mat2) # do the calculation and store the results in "multiplied"

print_matrix(multiplied) # finally print the results
```

You made a couple of mistakes:

1. You have to indent your function code for it to be considered code inside a function in Python
2. You have to initialize the result matrix somehow if you are doing the triple loop calculation (in the example I do it with list comprehensions so I get the right nested structure), otherwise your indexing into the result matrix will fail, since you are trying to access nested parts that will not be there
3. You have to either return the results from the `matrixmulti` function or print the results inside the function for it to be of any help

Hope this helps.

Comment: for some reason the indentation didn't come through and also for cross product of two matrices, the lengths isn't necessary to be same?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BATMAN\DAA_Lab\assignment22.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\BATMAN\DAA_Lab\assignment22.py", line 15, in main
    matrixmulti(m1,m2)
  File "C:\Users\BATMAN\DAA_Lab\assignment22.py", line 33, in matrixmulti
    if len(mat1[0]) != len(mat2): # Optional: check if "inner" dimensions match and throw an exception if they don't
IndexError: list index out of range
This is the error I am getting